# Passing data from django to seperate ChartJS file throws error

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to send data between a django view to a seperate file containing my chartJS chart.

```
const lineChart = document.getElementById('lineChart');

const interactionsListInput = document.getElementById('interactions_list');
const interactionsList = JSON.parse(interactionsListInput.value);

const labels = interactionsList.map(item => item[0]);
const data = interactionsList.map(item => item[1]);
console.log(interactionsList)
new Chart(lineChart, {
  type: 'line',

  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Interactions',
      data: data,
      backgroundColor: '#ff0084',
      color: '#ff0084',
      borderColor: '#ff0084',
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },

  options: {
    plugins: {
        legend: {
          display: false
        }
    },
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I was expecting the chart to render with the data being supplied by `interactions_list`

Im passing my data into my html page using:

`<input type="hidden" id="interactions_list" value="{{ interactions_list|safe }}">`

and the data of the `interactions_list` is in this format:

```
[['02/06/2023', 'None'], ['02/07/2023', 'None'], ['02/08/2023', 'None'], ['02/09/2023', 'None'], ['02/10/2023', 'None'], ['02/11/2023', 'None'], ['02/12/2023', '19026']]
```

but i get the following error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ''', "[['02/06/202"... is not valid JSON`

I'm not sure why this error is appearing.

I've tried
`<input type="hidden" id="interactions_list" value="{{ interactions_list|escapejs }}">`

To see if its some kinda of formation issue between Django and JS, but i no joy.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`interactions_list` is not valid json format as the error says. This seems to be an array of tuples or a nested array.

```
[['02/06/2023', 'None'], ['02/07/2023', 'None'], ['02/08/2023', 'None'], ['02/09/2023', 'None'], ['02/10/2023', 'None'], ['02/11/2023', 'None'], ['02/12/2023', '19026']]
```

json format is like the below

so your example data should be sort of like this

```
  {
   "interaction_list":[
      {
         "date":"02/06/2023",
         "value":"None"
      },
      {
         "date":"02/08/2023",
         "value":"None"
      }
   ]
}
```